# How to get keyset from a string in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a following String in Groovy:

```
[[{"qunit":{"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], [{"utest": {"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]
```

I need to get just the keys 'qunit' and 'utest'

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string represents a JSON document, so you need to use `JsonSlurper` first to parse it:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

final String json = '[[{"qunit":{"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], [{"utest": {"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]'

def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
```

If you print `list` variable you will see something like this:

```
[[[qunit:[total:0, passed:0, failed:0, skipped:0]]], [[utest:[total:0, passed:0, failed:0, skipped:0]]]]
```

Firstly, we would need to flatten the list:

```
list.flatten()
```

which returns a list like:

```
[[qunit:[total:0, passed:0, failed:0, skipped:0]], [utest:[total:0, passed:0, failed:0, skipped:0]]]
```

Flatting the initial list produces `List<Map<String, Object>>`. We can use spread operator `*` to execute `keySet()` method on each map stored in the the list:

```
list.flatten()*.keySet()
```

This part of the code produces a list of `List<List<String>>` type like:

```
[[qunit], [utest]]
```

Finally, we can convert it to `List<String>` by calling `flatten()` in the end, like:

```
list.flatten()*.keySet().flatten()
```

After applying the last operation we get a list like:

```
[qunit, utest]
```

And here is complete example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

final String json = '[[{"qunit":{"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], [{"utest": {"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]'

def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def keys = list.flatten()*.keySet().flatten()

assert keys == ['qunit', 'utest']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse that JSON string and then read the list:

```
def p = new JsonSlurper()
def list = 
    p.parseText("""[[{"qunit":{"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], 
                   [{"utest": {"total":0,"passed":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]""")

def keys = list.flatten().collect{it.keySet()}.flatten()
```

Result is `[qunit, utest]`

This obviously is specific to the layout of the input.